# Samsung S8 messenger saved images

Tags: facebook-messenger

I cannot find my saved facebook messenger images on my Samsung Galaxy S8 photos, i looked everywhere, in all my albums, pictures, downloads files etc.tried looking everywhere for my messenger photos, no luck what should i do.  help

Answer (score 2):

In case of FB Messenger you have to 'Save' image.

1. Click on the image in the Messenger app.
2. Click 'more' in the lower left corner of the screen.
3. Tap 'Save'.

Now the image is saved to your device and it can be seen in Gallery.

Dedicated folder:
   Internal Storage/Pictures/Messenger